# Turning a LED off with a combination of buttons during a "for" loop

Tags: for-loop, button, arduino, delay, led

I have a code in which a LED will light for a set period of time up depending on a combination of 3 buttons.

My problem is that once a combination begins, I can't seem to turn the LED off. It is assumed that when I press all the 3 buttons, the LED will turn off, no matter how much time it is left.

Here is the part that I have problems with:

```cpp
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
        for (int d=0; d<24;d++)
            if (buttonState1 == HIGH && buttonState2 == HIGH && buttonState3 == HIGH){
                d=24;
            }
        delay(1000)
    }
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
}
```

According to me the LED should turn on for 24sec then off, if the Button 1 is pressed, but turn off if all buttons are being pushed at the same time regardless of the time left.

Comment: According to the code, the LED only lights up for a second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a curled bracket:

```
if (buttonState1 == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    for (int d=0; d<24;d++){        // Missed bracket here
        if (buttonState1 == HIGH && buttonState2 == HIGH && buttonState3 == HIGH){
            d=24;
        }
        delay(1000)
    }
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
}
```

So the delay is now a part of the for-loop. The fact that you say it doesn't turn off if you pressed the three buttons could be because of the delay itself. You are stucking in 1 sec of doing nothing and then you check for something less than a millisecond. I assume if you press your buttons for a second or more it could work (as long as you have some digitalReads, which you didn't show to us). To avoid this you can use a timestamp instead of the delay:

```
long startTime = 0;

buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);

if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    startTime = millis();
    while(startTime + 24000 > millis() && startTime != 0){            
        // You have to read your buttons every loop. Might be also some problem in your code
        buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
        buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
        buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
        if (buttonState1 == HIGH && buttonState2 == HIGH && buttonState3 == HIGH){
            startTime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);

}
```